# Dynamically generated grid could not be draggable in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angularjs, angular, draggable

//using this in typescript file

```
      jQuery(function() {
            // initialize Packery
            var $grid = jQuery('.grid').packery({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                // columnWidth helps with drop positioning
                columnWidth: 100,
                rowHeight: 100
            });

            // make all items draggable
            var $items = $grid.find('.grid-item').draggable();
            // bind drag events to Packery
            $grid.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', $items);
        });
```

//using this in html file

```
         <div class="grid">   
     <div *ngFor=" let box of gridJSON " class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"  ></div>
    </div>
```

//Working fine for this

```
      <div class="grid">   
         <div  class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"  ></div>
     <div  class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"  ></div>
        </div>
```

//Not working for this

```
     <div class="grid">   
         <div *ngFor=" let box of gridJSON " class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"  ></div>
        </div>
```

When I am putting grid statically then draggable feature working fine but when I am creating grid using *ngFor , it's not working .

Comment: Because you are implementing draggable behavior wrong. How do you do it?

Comment: Because it doesn't work?

Comment: Please help me out , how can I implement draggable component for dynamic grid using same draggable plugin .

Comment: http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html

Comment: So how do you implement "draggablility"? Plugin or what? You should probably do it differently. Post your code, without it's hard to tell.

Comment: jQuery(function() {
            // initialize Packery
            var $grid = jQuery('.grid').packery({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                // columnWidth helps with drop positioning
                columnWidth: 100,
                rowHeight: 100
            });

            // make all items draggable
            var $items = $grid.find('.grid-item').draggable();
            // bind drag events to Packery
            $grid.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', $items);
        });

Comment: I am using this in .ts file for draggable feature , it's working for static grid but not working when I am trying to create dynamic grid usng *ngFor .

Comment: Please share some code where do you use it.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code, don't post them in comments, it's not readable.

Comment: I updated in question have a look

Comment: I call this in ngOnit

Comment: Try to use it inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: thnx yurzui .. now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

set a private variable in your component :

```
private packery: any;
```

Call the initGrid function (described below) in ngOnInit() like this:

```
ngOnInit() {           
   setTimeout(() => this.initGrid(), 0);
}
```

the setTimeout will wait for the ngFor from your html to finish generate your div grid-items.

The initGrid method:

```
initGrid() {
        let elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
        this.packery= new Packery(elem, {
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            gutter: 10,
            columnWidth: 250
        });

        var elems = this.packery.getItemElements();
        elems.forEach(gridItem => {
            var draggie = new Draggabilly(gridItem);
            // bind drag events to Packery
            this.packery.bindDraggabillyEvents(draggie);
        });
    }
```

If u don't like the initGrid, I think you can wrap your function in a setTimeout method.

Hope it helps.